# Stepping down 48V (from power over Ethernet) to 5V

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, voltage-regulator, ethernet

I'd like to use power over Ethernet to power an ATMega328 microcontroller at 5V, however PoE operates at around 48V for commercial PoE switches. How can I drop the voltage from 48V to 5V efficiently?

I've looked at voltage regulators and step down converters but I'm unsure if they are suitable. The microcontroller will be using less than 500mA.

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't start with the POE regulator module used by Arduino?  Google would find it faster than you can reply to this comment.

Answer (score 10):

As you correctly noted, a step down converter is the right thing to use.

You'll notice that all bigger semiconductor manufacturers have tools on their website to help you design a step-down converter from e.g. 48 V to 5 V for the current your device needs (500mA, as you say).

However, if your PoE-injector is truly standards-compliant (far from all are), then there will be no 48V on the Ethernet port until the device signals it needs that ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_over_Ethernet))

> The PSE can implement mode A or B or both. A PD indicates that it is standards-compliant by placing a 25 kΩ resistor between the powered pairs. If the PSE detects a resistance that is too high or too low (including a short circuit), no power is applied. This protects devices that do not support PoE.

In effect, it's probably easiest to just use one of the several "Power over Ethernet ICs"; generally, google is your friend, but let's directly link you to  some common matching PSE product lines:

- ST.com [product category](http://www.st.com/en/power-management/power-over-ethernet-ics.html?querycriteria=productId=SC1109);
- Texas Instruments [product category](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/powered-device-products.page#);
- Linear Technology's (now part of Analog Devices, Inc) [product category](http://www.linear.com/products/PoE_Power_Sourcing_Equipment_(PSE)), and one possible quick and dirty [solution](http://www.linear.com/solutions/3923) amongst many;

Note that PoE equipment typically is in the uncomfortable situation that they're trying to run power through communication lines. Since Ethernet uses differential signalling, you'll need typical ethernet signal transformers with a center tap on the network side if you want to use the cable for actual network, too:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRzNmC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, if you don't actually plan on using the Ethernet as ... Ethernet a) you might be doing something strange and b) you might remove the magnetics (=transformers) and just terminate the ethernet lines with their specific impedance – 150Ω:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=https%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRyPu6.png)</sup>

Note that the schematic above is but a dirty, inaccurate hack to make the ethernet port not see an open circuit at the end of your twisted pairs and interpret the port as unconnected.

Comment: Another possible solution is [here](http://www.linear.com/solutions/3923)

Comment: Linear Technology's PSE product line and solutions page is [here](http://www.linear.com/products/PoE_Power_Sourcing_Equipment_(PSE))

Comment: @MyOtherHead can you try editing my answer and add the link? That'd be 2 easy reputation points for you to gain as soon as I accept your edit.

Comment: To be POE standards (802.3af/at/bt) compliant you can supply a range of voltages on the Ethernet cable ranging from 37-57 V DC. However if you are not trying to be standards compliant (ie DIY/Hobby) there are many 12 V and 24 V POE injector power supplies available. The main point is to not exceed the current carrying capacity of the cable. Since you are only using 5 V @500 mA on the client end, a 12 V supply at a minimum of  250 mA would seem to be all you need.